# "NoReverseMatch" Reverse for 'by_rubric' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I'm extremely new to Python and Django. I tried to make a code from exercise work, and it was fine for a while, but since I tried to implement templates inheritance I've got this error on my homepage. Rest are working fine...for now. I tried to find solution in similar topics and django docs.,but it didn't help me. Please give me a hand on this one, cause having error at line 0 when I have only 1,2,3.. is really frustrating. Due to my lack of knowledge it's hard to understand even which file is responsible for this error.

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /bboard/
Reverse for 'by_rubric' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['bboard/(?P<rubric_id>[0-9]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/bboard/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'by_rubric' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['bboard/(?P<rubric_id>[0-9]+)/$']
Exception Location: D:\django\venv_1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  D:\django\venv_1\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Rubric
from .models import Bb
from .forms import BbForm


def index(request):
    bbs = Bb.objects.all()
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    context = {'bbs': bbs, 'rubrics': rubrics}
    return render(request, 'bboard/index.html', context)


def by_rubric(request, rubric_id):
    bbs = Bb.objects.filter(rubric=rubric_id)
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    current_rubric = Rubric.objects.get(pk=rubric_id)
    context = {'bbs': bbs, 'rubrics': rubrics, 'current_rubric': current_rubric}
    return render(request, 'bboard/by_rubric.html', context)


class BbCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/create.html'
    form_class = BbForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['rubrics'] = Rubric.objects.all()
        return context
```

my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import BbCreateView
from .views import index, by_rubric

urlpatterns = [
    path('add', BbCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),
    path('<int:rubric_id>/', by_rubric, name='by_rubric'),
    path('', index, name='index'),
    ]
```

layout/basic.html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %} - Bill Board</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Advertisements</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
        <a href="{% url 'add' %}">Add New</a>
        {% for rubric in rubrics %}
        <a href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %}">{{ rubric.name }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </nav>
    <section>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'layout/basic.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for bb in bbs %}
<div class="b">
    <h2>{{ bb.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ bb.content }}</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %}">{{ rubric.name }}</a></p>
    <p>{{ bb.published|date:'d.m.Y H:i:s' }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

by_rubric.html

```
{% extends 'layout/basic.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ current_rubric.name }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Rubric: {{ current_rubric.name }}</h2>
{% for bb in bbs %}
<div>
    <h2>{{ bb.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ bb.content }}</p>
    <p>{{ bb.published|date:'d.m.Y H:i:s' }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `<p><a href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %}">{{ rubric.name }}</a></p>` makes not much sense, since you never pass a variable `rubric` to the `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this raises an error is the line:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %}">{{ rubric.name }}</a></p>
```

in the `index.html` template. You do not pass a `rubric` object ot the `index.html` template, so `rubric.pk` does not exists, and is resolved to the empty string, and this does does not match with the `<int:pk>` path converter.

You can replace this with:

```
{% for rubric in rubrics %}
<p><a href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %}">{{ rubric.name }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great!!!! Thank you  very much!!! ))))) I wish i could knew more to solve these issues myself, but still, i'm not gonna stop learning )).

Answer (score 0):

```
{% extends 'layout/basic.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for bb in bbs %}
<div class="b">
    <h2>{{ bb.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ bb.content }}</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'by_rubric' **bb.rubric.pk** %}">{{ rubric.name }}</a></p>
    <p>{{ bb.published|date:'d.m.Y H:i:s' }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

in **index.html**

Comment: `rubric` is not an property of `bb` object, so he cannot do `bb.rubric`. Also, what about those double asterisks `**`, why did you add them?!